# Can I include carrots in Tortilla de Patatas and can I use a casserole dish to make it taller?

Tags: oven, frying, spanish-cuisine, omelette, tortilla

I want to make Tortilla de Patatas but I have extra carrots that I would like to use somewhere. Can I include them in the frying phase? And can the dish be cooked in a casserole dish in the oven to make a very tall 'omelet'?

Comment: Since you ask about another addition in a comment below, I hope you won't object to me mentioning that the one "standard" addition is onion. That is to say, in Spain tortilla de patatas can be described as "with onion" or "without onion".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to add carrots, make sure you cut them small enough (since it takes quite a while to get them soft). I'm not 100% sure it would be a good fit, but that's up to you.

You certainly can make a tortilla in the oven, I've done so in a spring form. I think I did it for about 45 min in an oven of 180°C/350°F. But this depends of course on how much food you use and how big your form is. Just keep an eye on it, the egg should be fully cooked and the potatoes soft.

Comment: would tomatoes be better than carrots to add?

Comment: In my opinion? Yes. I sometimes slice a tomato and put the slices on top. So don't add it to the stir-fry.

Answer (score 4):

Tortilla de patatas can be mixed with some other vegetables in order to make some varieties (for example: tortilla campera). But I've never seen a tortilla with carrots, although I understand you need to cook somewhere those carrots. I'd love to know how it looks and tastes! ;)

If you add carrots, make sure carrots are at least a bit cooked before adding to any phase of the tortilla. If I were you, I would take one of these 2 options:

- I would boil carrots and add them to the egg mix right after fried potatoes and onions.
- Or, in case you want carrots to have some olive oil + onions + fried potatoes flavour, I would at least blanch them (or boil until they are tender / al dente) before adding to the frying phase (as cooking carrots takes longer than potatoes) at the same time than potatoes.

You can make it in the oven if you find it more convenient, why not? Just so you know that is far from a spanish traditional way of cooking it ;)

In case your concern is about making a taller tortilla, you can do that in a frying pan too (no need for an oven to do that). It only takes some more practice to learn until you do a taller one. Why? Basically because it implies that you have to fill much more your frying pan with more tortilla mixture. Which means when you would flip tortilla upside down you may find it heavier than other times and also you have to move quicker too because mixture tends to spread if it's too tall. Also, you should let tortilla in the heat for sometime longer too in order the inside is properly cooked (bearing in mind that the heat can't be very high as the outside could burn).

Well, I hope this help and good luck with your carrot-tortilla! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd most likely slice the carrots very thinly and fry them just before I did the potatoes.  Boiling to soften and drying before frying would be another possibility if you're not being lazy.

But I would *not* only boil them.  You want them going into the eggs while they're still hot, so the egg kinda congeals around them and binds well.  If you were to add cold carrots, or hot-but-wet carrots, it wouldn't adhere correctly.

And if you did it in a casserole dish, I would argue that it's a crustless, dairy-free quiche, as you're just not going to get the same fried exterior that you get with a spanish tortilla.  If you pre-heated the casserole dish with some oil in it, you'd get closer, but it's going to be closer to a frittata.

And one other tip for larger tortillas -- I use a pot lid, rather than a plate to flip it.  Use one that's curved or has a bit of a lip to catch the oil and is a little bit bigger than the pan you're using.  Slide the tortilla onto the lid, place the pan upside down on the lid, then quickly flip them both over.  I find that having a handle is easier for me than when using a plate.

Answer (score 1):

You can put almost anything in tortillas. With tortilla de papas, you would typically fry the potatoes before hand, I would add the carrots there since those take a while to cook, like potatoes. I add carrots to them sometimes, also squash or make it with spinach.

You can cook them in the oven in a baking dish or cast iron pan. Cook at 190C, time would depend on the size.